Early cryptography and spies movie
I remember seeing this Hollywood movie on tv. It takes place in late 50's or early 60's about an expert cryptographer who works for the US or UK government recruiting women for an office he directs because he thinks that women are better at discovering patterns. There are computers but voluminous ones. I remember some spies elements on it but very little more. Can someone identify it? Thanks in advance. 
Edit: Other details: I remember seeing this movie dubbed on a b/w tv in the early 80's but I suspect it was already a b/w movie. I think it was released on late 50's.

This could be Sebastian from 1968
From wikipedia:

Mr. Sebastian is a former Oxford professor, who in the late 60s
  directs the all-female decoding office of British Intelligence. One
  day, while running through the streets of Oxford to attend the
  bestowing of an honorary degree on his friend the Prime Minister,
  Sebastian runs into Rebecca (Becky) Howard and her jeep. After
  insulting Sebastian on the spot, Becky is intrigued by him and follows
  him to the ceremony. After Becky is able to spell her own name
  backwards, he gives her a phone number to call if she wants an
  unspecified "job."

The entire film is on youtube (not sure about legality so haven't linked directly)
[Edit: as per Richard's suggestion: youtube]

Yes, this totally is it. Thanks! And thanks for the youtube link too.
